# Origin url is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, cross-domain

I know there are many questions already regarding this error. But, I'm still not able to get this working even after setting the header

```
         "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"
```

on my server side.

Here is my spring mvc controller method:

```
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="dummy/{num}")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Result> dummy(@PathVariable String num)
    {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(num);
        final Result result = new Result();
        result.setAddition(n+20);
        result.setMultiplication(n*20);
        result.setSubtraction(n-20);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        ResponseEntity<Result> ent = new ResponseEntity<Result>(result,headers,HttpStatus.CREATED);
        return ent;
    }
```

And here is my AJAX call from Jquery

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8010/Probe_Rest_Service/test/dummy/9",
    type: "get",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: { 
    "Content-type" : "application/json"
    },

    success: function(data){

        console.log("It worked!");
        alert(data);
    },

    error: function(){
        // enable the inputs
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

I tried calling my REST api from dev-http client for chrome and it works fine (the response header has Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* set) . But, when i call it from my html file, i get the error.

I use JBoss for my rest api and tomcat for hosting my client webpage

Comment: Note, `crossDomain: true,` isn't needed.

Comment: Are you doing the html file test from a webserver using chrome?

Comment: @KevinB Yes, that is right

Comment: If you open the chrome console. what headers are being returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're sending the request with content type `application/json` the client is forced to do a CORS pre-flight request.

The [CORS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) says that any content type other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain` requires a pre-flight request to determine whether the header is allowed.

Therefore, you'll need to handle the pre-flight request (HTTP method = `OPTIONS`).

To make it simple, let the server respond with the header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
```

That will allow all request headers.

**UPDATE**

I read your question again, and found something I don't understand: Why are you sending the `Content-Type` header in the first place for an HTTP GET request? This is not correct.

Just remove

```
headers: { 
   "Content-type" : "application/json"
}
```

and try again. That might fix it!

Comment: For POST request, I still get the cross origin error and I'm trying to fix it by handling the pre-flight request as you suggested. For this , do you mean I have to just send an empty response with HTTP header set to "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *" ?